# Need to capture File -> New Window event of Internet Explorer in JSP-Servlet application

Tags: javascript, jsp, internet-explorer, servlets

I am having JSP-SERVLET application and i am able to capture the event CTRL+N from keyboard and invalidating the session object.

But i am facing issue when user open a new window from file menu : FILE -> New Window the same page gets open but i am not able to invalidate the session. To summarize the issue

1. CTRL+N - > Capture event invalidate the session (Working fine)
2. Go to FILE Menu -> New Window. Not able to capture the event and user can access the page with same session.

Please provide your suggestions only for Internet Explorer not for any other browser.

Comment: First suggestion: do not do this, it is futile. Second suggestion: why to make a web application to be used on internet explorer only? Really bad decision. Third suggestion: you **cannot** control browser options using JavaScript, it is insecure (just imagine your web application controlling the client browser: opening lot of windows until the RAM explodes, or start firing downloads of files [viruses as well] and opening them after being downloaded).

Comment: 1. This is a bad idea. 2. This is impossible.